# Add a if clause into a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I got a query

```
sql_query := ' Select A,B,C from table where A = 'DG54FDG45SD' and B = 'FS487' ;
```

and I want to add it a if clause like this :

```
sql_query := ' Select A,B,C,D from table where A = 'DG54FDG45SD' and B = 'FS487' and  (if C  = 'AR' then AND  D in (select uid from table2 where id = 'DGF'));
```

Thanks !

Comment: and (c <> AR or D IN ...)

Comment: @jarlh No I mean , If C = AR i want to add a the where clause D in

Comment: Just what I showed you. If c <> AR, the D IN is not evaluated. If c = AR, D IN is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this with an `if` in a `where` clause -- simply because it is not necessary.  You can arrive at the same logic uses basic boolean operations:

```
where A = 'DG54FDG45SD' and
      B = 'FS487' and
      (D in (select uid from table2 where id = 'DGF') or
       C <> 'AR'
      )
```

If you need to take `NULL` into account:

```
where A = 'DG54FDG45SD' and
      B = 'FS487' and
      (D in (select uid from table2 where id = 'DGF') or
       C <> 'AR' or C is null
      )
```